# Non-intrusive super/subscripts using slanted Greek with tensor?

Tags: subscripts, superscripts, tensor

I was quite happy with how the [`tensor`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tensor) package is able to typeset beautiful tensor expressions … until I decided to use the ISO convention for my [Christoffel symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[slantedGreek]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{mathtools}% for `cases*'
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{cases*}
\upGamma\indices{^\mu_{\sigma\rho}}    & \TeX\ convention \\
\Gamma\indices{^\mu_{\sigma\rho}}      & ISO convention   \\
\Gamma{}^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\sigma\rho} & Ad hoc attempt
\end{cases*}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Christoffel symbols]

As shown in the picture, direct use of `\indices` leads to “intrusive” `\sigma` into the space under `\mu` (or, “intrusive” `\mu` into the space above `\sigma`), which is understandably caused by the slanted `\Gamma`.

This problem is much more visible when I use MathTime Pro 2 as my math font:

[image: mtpro2 used]

When switching from the TeX convention to the ISO convention, I’d like my tensor super/subscripts to be non-intrusive. Is there anything I can do/modify so I don’t have to manually change every `\indices` using the “ad hoc” approach?

Comment: You can just put an empty group after `\gamma` and before `\indices`: `\Gamma{}\indices{^\mu_{\sigma\rho}}`.

Comment: @campa -- this seems worth an answer, just to keep the question from being unanswered,

Comment: @barbarabeeton Uh, I'd forgotten this one. However, I'm not sure what the package is doing and I don't really like writing answers which just work without me knowing why. I'll think about it in the weekend, if you don't mind...